# Getting integer for Facebook notifications/inboxes/friends

Tags: java, facebook, restfb

I know there are quite a few questions about Facebook but I couldn't find one which answered my question. Basically what I'm trying to do is get an integer for how many notifications, inboxes, friend requests in Java. Does anyone know how to or can provide a link to something which will answer my question?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using a library like http://restfb.com/ or http://facebook4j.org/ to talk to the Facebook API from your Java application.

With RestFB it would look something like the following:

```
FacebookClient publicOnlyFacebookClient = new DefaultFacebookClient();
Connection<Notification> notifications = 
facebookClient.fetchConnection("me/notifications", Notification.class, 
Parameter.with("fields","title"));
```

Via notifications.getData() you have access to the notifications and can count them.

Comment: Okay so, RestFB works. The problem is that I need the permission manage_notifications. I select it and then when I get an access token it deselects it, I think I have to apply for it somehow but i'm not sure how. Do you know?

Comment: I believe you have to add this permission to the app you register at developers.facebook.com

Comment: I suggest you call `me/notifications?summary=1&limit=0` and use JsonObject.class as response type in the RestFB call. So you can access the `unseen_count` field. The direct access is not supported by RestFB, but you may create a custom type class.